# How can I disable 128 bit ciphers in apache?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I am using this SSL Conf:

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!RSA:!CAMELLIA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4:!SHA1:!SHA256:!SHA384
```

Please help! I am unable to find any solutions.

When I use ssllabs.com to check my website my cipher is always <100%. So, I heard that disabling 128 bit ciphers will get me to the full %. And I want to be as secure as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of listing `ALL` and then removing what you don't want you could just list the accepted ciphersuites, e.g.

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
```

Also, you shouldn't focus on getting A+ 100% on the SSL Labs test. There's no such thing as 100% security, but only security against a risk. What's your risk model? Focusing on tests might even give you false sense of security. The most useful part of the test starts after the grading. There, you can make a [suitable compromise](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/210167) between security and compatibility. Are you willing to lose the visitors with older browsers that do not support any of your ciphersuites?

Comment: What would be the most secure, and also allow most devices?

Comment: I've already linked my answer that discusses that exact question. [RFC 7525, 4.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7525#section-4.2) is always a good start.

Comment: Maybe I should stick with `SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES`

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana See https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ for continuously updated advice.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have setup everything now. I have support for many devices. And I even have 100% on all in ssllabs. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Good advice. I hadn't realized TLS 1.2 is now completely removed from their modern profile, which is good.